# POST fails with ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to String error

Tags: react-native, fetch

I'm working in `React Native`, I use `PHP` for backend and when I use fetch `POST` request I get so strange error, and I dont know why it happens. I checked the url so it works no problem, also normal `fetch()` is working without `POST` but when I try to post it happens. When I try it in local server fetch `POST` works.. but in server, I get this error :

> ERROR : com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap cannot be cast to
> java.lang.String

React native codes :

```
fetch('http://xxx/react_test1', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: inputName,
    email: inputEmail,
    phone: inputPhone
  }),
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    Alert.alert(responseJson);
  }).catch((error) => {
  alert(error);
});
```

Comment: This request does look good to me. Can you debug by checking the payload body and see if the values are valid?

Comment: I guess answer was Alert.alert('string', responseJson), try like this because Alert.alert requires 2 value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alert.alert receives an string, and what you're getting from the fetch response is internally a `com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap` object (which is what the native implementation for fetch returns).
You can try:

```
Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
```

If you were using iOS you'll get a completely different error:

```
Exception '-[_NSFrozenDictionaryM length]: unrecognized selector  ...
```

Comment: ok i will check alert part of the code and change it and let you know .

Comment: I checked now it gives other error but inside of alert, so we fixed this one. new Error is : {"message":"",exception":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel...

Comment: I Think its about Laravel / PHP part, so I need to fix there. then thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Alert.alert only accepts string as input.

Use `alert()` instead to show the popup.

Example: `alert("Response: ", responseJson)`

Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

So with fetch() in javascript you need headers: {} but when switching over to RNFetchBlob you should put the headers directly in the {}

```
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";


const aPath = Platform.select({ ios: DocumentDir, android: DownloadDir });
const fPath = aPath + '/' + Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2) + '.xls';
```

Also if you want to add body in the request then directly add it there.

```
For example:-
RNFetchBlob.config({
  // response data will be saved to this path if it has access right.
  path: fPath,
}).fetch('POST', URL, {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: token,
  },
JSON.stringify(reqBody)
)
.then(res => {
console.log("response body>>>",res);
})
.catch(function (err) {
console.log(err);
});
```

that's all enjoy your coding...